# Links based by id for iframes

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, hyperlink

So here's the thing, I have a php site and for some reasons I have to display all info (except the menus) on iframes (I know, bad SEO, old school).

So my menu call different links and display it on the iframe by giving the iframe an `id` and the link the `target="id-name"`.

As you can imagine I cannot send the `services` section because I don't have a link to display with all my layout.

So, my question is:
Is there a way to give my link an `id` and use it as a link so it could be like: `http://example.com/#services` with php, jquery, .htaccess

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can check hash value (#services) with [location.hash](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) and then change appriopriate iframe with javascript depending in it